# Need to select and remove numbers from file names I'm using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Here is what I'm doing:
I went through my Firefox bookmarks and removed what I no longer need or want.
I have used "FireShot" add-on and saved over 200 bookmarked articles as `.pdf` files.
Now I'm stuck with file names like `FireShot Capture ### - Name of article.pdf`.

I want to remove the `FireShot Capture ### -`  the numbers are random in some titles. I have some numbers even missing.

So here is what I did with "Notepad++":

I went to "Downloads" "FireShot" "FireShot Capture" and then I used "Right Click + Copy as Path" after selecting them all.
Then I placed the copied file names into "Notepad++".

Now my files look like this:

```
"C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\FireShot\FireShot Capture ### - "Article Name".pdf"
```

I want to remove the `C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\FireShot\FireShot Capture ### -`.
But since the 3 numbers are all different and not the same like 111 for every file name, I don't know how to remove "Random" numbers.

I have tried `\d+` but it dose not work I have tried
`C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\FireShot\FireShot Capture \d+ -`
but I don't know how to do this correctly.

I have even tried to enclose the `\d+` in `"` and I still can't get this to work.

Any advice please.

Thank You!

Comment: Do you want to rename the files in their folder or only keep filename inside the bookmark file? Please, edit your question and add some lines and expected result.

Comment: (1) I wanted to save some of the bookmarks as pdf so I could remove them from the bookmarks on my firefox browser (2) I have several pdf files now that have "FireShot Capture ### - " I just want to keep the file name and remove the text and 3 random numbers after Capture but before -. (3) I want to keep them as pdf files and then I will move them to drive inside a folder later. And then remove them from my laptop. (4) I moved the bookmarks from Windows 10 laptop to Windows 11 laptop by using the html file. And I removed several bookmarks and now I moved them back to my older windows 10 laptop.

Comment: Bulk Rename Utility is useful in cases like this. bulkrenameutility.co.uk

Comment: If you want to remove everything to the left of the `-`, can't you just ignore the numbers and remove everything to the left of the `-`? (Possible problem if `-` occurs in the file path)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Powershell or PowerRename found in [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases) instead of Notepad++.

Open Powershell, then type the following cmdlets:

```ps
cd "C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\FireShot\"
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -Replace '.+\d+\s-\s',''}
```

Comment: I have given this a try as well and found out I have about 20 or so of the same pdf files I didn't notice until I tried to rename them. This helped with renaming quickly. Instead of using the notepad++ to remove some text and then change the file names one at a time I decided to do this instead. Thank you.

Comment: I regularly use PowerRename found in PowerToys. The visual indicator of what will happen before you execute the rename is very useful

Comment: @JoSSte You are correct with PowerRename. You can see in advance whether the files will be renamed properly or not.

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?Fireshot Capture \d+ -`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # begining of line
.+?                 # 1 or more any character but newline
Fireshot Capture    # literally
\d+                 # 1 or more digits
 -                  # space, hyphen, space
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all the names have exactly the same prefix with exactly
the same number of characters as in `FireShot Capture ### - whatever`,
run a Command Prompt (cmd) inside the folder
`C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\FireShot` (use the
[cd command](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)),
and enter the following command-line :

```
ren "??????????????????????*" "///////////////////////*"
```

While `?` and `*` have their usual meaning, each `/` character causes
one matched character to be omitted from the matched string.

Reference : [The REN command](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html).